# Rails 7 Prevent html form from submit to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an HTML form in erb view template

```
<form id="megapayForm" name="megapayForm" method="POST">
      <label for="merId" >MerchantId:</label>
      <input type="text" id="merId" name="merId" ><br><br>
      <label for="currency">Currency:</label>
      <input type="text" id="currency" name="currency" ><br><br>
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

submit.js

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace', 
   success: function(data){
            

            
        },
   complete: function(){
      $("#" + formId).attr("action", domain + "acb.do");
      setTimeout(function(){ paymentForm.submit(); }, 100);
   }
});
```

and rails controller

```
class transaction
   def index
   end
end
```

Every time i press submit, instead of redirect to `domain + "acb.do"` , it being redirect to rails server transaction#create
How can i make the form being submit and redirect to `domain + "acb.do"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing `<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">`

to `<button id="submit">Submit</button>`. So when I press the button it does not call to server but only the javascript function